# Knex.Js Ignore Duplicates with BatchInsert on PostgreSQL

Tags: javascript, duplicates, insert, psql, knex.js

For regular inserts with Knex.Js you can do something like this in order to ignore any duplicate when inserting:

```
knex('tableName')
  .insert({
    email: "ignore@example.com",
    name: "John Doe"
  })
  .onConflict('email')
  .ignore()
```

I'm trying to do that for batchInsert, but I'm still getting duplicate errors:

```
const newUsers = await knex.batchInsert("user", filteredUsers, 1000).returning('email').onConflict('userId')
 .ignore();
```

Is there any way to do this with batchInsert?

Documentation gives this example but it's done with the regular Insert method, not with batchInsert. I tried it with no success
https://knexjs.org/guide/query-builder.html#onconflict

[Documentation Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2A0A.png)

Answer (score 0):

`.batchInsert` (source code [here](https://github.com/knex/knex/blob/master/lib/execution/batch-insert.js) and docs [here](https://knexjs.org/guide/utility.html#batchinsert)) is just a util function which wraps `.insert`.

It splits the list of items to insert into chunks (via [lodash chunk](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#chunk)), with a default size of 10k if no `chunkSize` is provided, then inserts those chunks sequentially in 1 transaction.

If you wanted a batch insert which ignores on conflict you could do something like:

```
const batchInsertIgnoreOnConflict = async (users: User[]): Promise<User[]> => {
  const chunkedUsers = chunk(users, 1_000);
  const insertedUsers: User[] = [];
  await knex.transaction(async (trx) => {
    for (const chunk of chunkedUsers) {
      insertedUsers.push(
        await trx<User>('users')
          .insert(chunk)
          .returning('email')
          .onConflict('userId')
          .ignore()
      );
    }
  });
  return insertedUsers;
};
```